# Running Plasmoid under NOTKDE (e.g. Fluxbox) - Plasma/DeviceNotifier

Tags: kde, window-manager, desktop, desktop-environment, plasma

Is there way to run [Plasma/DeviceNotifier](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/DeviceNotifier) under another WM to KWin/KDE (e.g. Fluxbox).

To be more specific, I have currently configured KDE, but I work remotely thorough SSH -Y + X-forwarding. So running `plasma-desktop` might run all other Plasmoids/Widgets. I'd like to run only one : DeviceNotifier.

As I see it runs thought libs, no standalone executable there:

```
~$ pacman -Ql | grep devicenoti
kdebase-workspace /usr/lib/kde4/plasma_applet_devicenotifier.so
kdebase-workspace /usr/lib/kde4/plasma_engine_devicenotifications.so
kdebase-workspace /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-applet-devicenotifier.desktop
kdebase-workspace /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-dataengine-devicenotifications.desktop
kdebindings-python /usr/share/sip/PyKDE4/solid/devicenotifier.sip
kde-l10n-pl /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/plasma_applet_devicenotifier.mo
kdelibs /usr/include/solid/devicenotifier.h
```

So... how to run it ?

### Update:

Running `plasma-desktop` **does not work**.

I run on my laptop:

```
laptop$ xinit;
laptop$ ssh -Y desktop;
desktop$ fluxbox #X forwarding
```

So I run fluxbox on remote machine ("Desktop").

When I run in such situation `plasma-desktop` I end-up with whole screen messed up with all widgets I normally use on remote machine when I work on it locally.
There are few problems there : (1) On desktop I have six times more screen space, (2) when I work remotely I do not need most of stuff I need when I work locally (3) I'm afraid of running another instance remotely of all those widgets and stuff, when it's already running on desktop.

That's why I am asking about running only one widget.

It can be `plasma-desktop`, but running only one widget, but not whole stuff I have setup and running on desktop locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the executable your looking for is called `plasma-desktop`.  I would try it out first, and if your satisfied with the results, then set it to autostart.  You are required to install a good chunk of the KDE dependencies to make it happen, but should not have a problem running just the plasmoids.

I will say this, plasmoids are the best desktop widgets around.  It becomes obvious once you compare the offerings of other available engines.   Unfortunately they are not the easiest to write, and they are highly integrated with the KDE DE.  You would get a much lighter environment running a light standalone widget engine.  I suspect though, because of your specified applet, that alternative web widgets are not what you want.  If you are having trouble with clean automounting, which can be an issue on clean install Flux/Black/OpenBox, good lightweight udisks/udev scripts are available from packages.

**Update:** In response to new issues.

It's possible to run single plasmoids, in their own window.  You would need to use `plasmoidviewer` to run the Device Notifier.  It's known for its use in developing widgets, and also considered fairly ugly.  However it should work, if you only desire to run the one single widget.

Comment: Running `plasma-desktop` DOES NOT WORK ! I end-up with whole screen covered with plasma background and all other widgets I've normally on remote machine when I work on it locally. I want to log on machine remotly and run only selected widgets.

Comment: @Grzegorz Wierzowiecki, have you tried my updated answer?  If it worked, or really even if not, consider accepting  my answer.  I'm almost 95% sure exactly what you want, does not exist in a better form.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :D `plasmoidviewer systemtray` runs system tray with `devicedriver` inside ! :) How I've found it: `plasmapkg -l | grep device` gave empty results. Running with path to `plasma_applet_devicenotifier.so` gave no success. So I've came with an idea, that `applet` is not just `plasmoid` and might need a container, so I tried `systemtray`. Most important : it works :). Finally I can access my devices when I log remotely (`ssh -Y` - X11 forwarding) nicely. *Could you confirm, Is my guess (that "applet" is not just plasmoid and needs container like "systemtray" plasmoid ?) right ?*

Comment: @Grzegorz Wierzowiecki: I'm actually not sure myself, I'm really a just a heavy Ex-KDE user.  Truthfully ... I don't even like any sort of desktop widgets, so its not my strongest field.  Really excited, you found a way to make it happen!!!   I even considered running plasma with OpenBox, specifically for Device Notifier.  Although with solid udisks scripts, It became unnecessary.  I really must admit, it's almost the most useful applet around.